# How to set listener on Slack channel?

Tags: php, slack-api, slack

I need to set listener for Slack channel, which will be listen new messages, and send them to the address by request. Is it possible? Can i do this, if I have http address, non https.

Comment: Did you investigate slack API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use an [outgoing webhook](https://api.slack.com/outgoing-webhooks). It will send all messages from a specific channel to an url you specify. Afaik it also works with HTTP, although HTTPS is recommended.

If will only work for public channels though. If you want a "listener" for a private channel, you will need to use a bot. Easiest approach in my opinion would be to use the [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api). Also works with HTTP in my experience, but again that would not be a secure choice.